# How to parse text in <li> tags without ID, ClassName...?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, parsing, dom, webbrowser-control

I am doing a school project in VB.Net for filtering infos out of webpages loaded by the WebBrowser Control. I stuck at some point where the html code has no identifiers like ID, ClassTags and so on.... What is the best solution to get the infos out of the webpage?

I already tried to get it over the top class `<ul class="TopInfo">` to get the innertext but it just prints out everything between the `<ul></ul>` Tags.

`<ul class="TopInfo">
        <li><strong>Bargeld:</strong> 1,106,378 €</li>
        <li><strong>Bank:</strong>  0 €</li>
</ul>`

I need to get these values:

`Bargeld: 1,106,378 €`
and `Bank: 0 €`

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it to work thankfully.

For future interests here is the code i used:

```
           For each h As HtmlElement In Form1.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("ul")
            if Not Object.ReferenceEquals(h.GetAttribute("className"), Nothing) AndAlso h.GetAttribute("className").Equals("TopInfo") Then
                MsgBox(h.InnerText)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Tip: Instead of writing such a long statement like `If Not Object.ReferenceEquals(h.GetAttribute("className"), Nothing)` you can do: `If h.GetAttribute("className") IsNot Nothing`.